# How to get /usr/bin/env ruby to point to the correct ruby environment?

Tags: 10.04, ruby, rails

So I was making a cgi ruby script and had the following at the top of the script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'action_pack'
 require 'cgi'
```

After a couple of hours of not getting "/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory" error and google searching, I uninstalled my system ruby 1.8.7 (I also had 1.9.3 installed via rvm) by doing [sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95/completely-remove-ruby-rails-gems).  I still get the error.  When I type "which ruby", I get `/home/homeuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`.  Does anyone have any insight as to how to fix this problem?

Here is what echo $PATH yields:

```
/home/homeuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rsoc326/bin:/home/homeuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/homeuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/homeuser/.rvm/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/homeuser/.rvm/bin
```

I have this same setup on my desktop and I don't have the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr/bin/env ruby` should be pointing to the RVM ruby.

But lets check your setup

1. Check the contents of your `~/.profile`, it should contain something like these 2 lines:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
   ```
2. Second, check your installed ruby version:

   ```
   rvm list
   ```

   this should output something like the following:

   ```
   rvm rubies

   =* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]

   # => - current
   # =* - current && default
   #  * - default
   ```

   if not, try running `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`
3. **When trying to run your script as root, be sure to use `rvmsudo ./yourscript.rb` instead of `sudo ./yourscript.rb`, this makes sure it sets the correct `$PATH`.**

Let me know the outcome of the above three steps.

Answer (score 4):

I added `#!/home/homeuser/.rvm/bin/ruby` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.  So I guess this means that `/usr/bin/env` points to the system ruby, and not any of the rvm rubies.

Problem solved, although it would be nice to be able to use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` so I can move my ruby script from Desktop to Laptop without having to change `#!/home/homeuser/.rvm/bin/ruby` (slightly different path on my desktop due to different user name). Maybe a symbolic link?