# What is the correct way to completely remove an application?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I've searched the net for such information and found different command lines, like these ones:

```
sudo apt-get remove application
sudo apt-get remove application*

sudo apt-get remove --purge application
sudo apt-get remove --purge application*

sudo apt-get purge application
sudo apt-get purge application*
```

So, what is the correct way? Is it necessary to use that "*"?

After that, I also found these commands:

```
sudo updatedb
sudo locate application
sudo rm -rf (file/folder name)
```

Comment: Some of your questions might be answered in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software

Comment: `application*` can on occasion give unexpected results - for example, if you have a file in the current directory named `application_information`, the shell would expand it before it's passed to apt-get.  If this is happening and you do want the literal asterisk, you can use `application\*` or `'application*'`

Comment: `application*` is even more dangerous where there are no files in the current directory: `apt-get` uses regular expressions, no glob patterns. People have almost wiped the whole system trying to remove `wine*`.

Comment: Can you accept an answer? To be grateful to people who answered you.

Comment: Neither `application*` nor `application\*` is safe! Quoting `*` with ``\`` or `'` `'` only *increases* the risk, ensuring `*` is passed as-is to `apt-get` (though it usually is anyway!), causes `apt-get` to interpret the argument as a regex. In a regex `*` means "zero or more of the preceding character." A common form of the mistake is to uninstall `wine*`, removing all packages with `win` (not `wine`, `win`) *anywhere* in their names and all packages depending on any of them. See [this explanation](https://askubuntu.com/q/431604) and [possible fixes](https://askubuntu.com/q/249367). @Izkata

Comment: @EliahKagan Hm, didn't know it would go regex instead of just globbing (still not exactly good but that would at least be reasonable).  But in that case, the original has the same problem - if bash doesn't find something to expand to, the asterisk is passed anyway.

Answer (score 903):

- `apt-get remove packagename`

  will remove the binaries, but not the configuration or data files of the package `packagename`. It will also leave dependencies installed with it on installation time untouched.
- `apt-get purge packagename` or `apt-get remove --purge packagename`

  will remove about *everything* regarding the package `packagename`, but not the dependencies installed with it on installation. Both commands are equivalent.

  Particularly useful when you want to 'start all over' with an application because you messed up the configuration. However, it does not remove configuration or data files residing in users home directories, usually in hidden folders there. There is no easy way to get those removed as well.
- `apt-get autoremove`

  removes orphaned packages, i.e. installed packages that used to be installed as an dependency, but aren't any longer. Use this after removing a package which had installed dependencies you're no longer interested in.
- `aptitude remove packagename` or `aptitude purge packagename` (likewise)

  will also attempt to remove other packages which were required by `packagename` on but are not required by any remaining packages. Note that `aptitude` only remembers dependency information for packages that it has installed.

And many more exist. Lower-level `dpkg`-commands can be used (advanced), or GUI tools like Muon, Synaptic, Software Center, etc. **There's no single 'correct way' of removing applications or performing other tasks interacting with your package management.**

The list you found are just examples. Make sure you understand the meanings and try out what it wants to do before accepting the action (you need to press `Y` before it actually performs the actions as proposed).

The asterisk version in the question is **probably wrong**; `apt-get` accepts a regular expression and not a glob pattern as the shell. So what happens with

```
sudo apt-get remove application*
```

is the following:

1. The shell tries to expand `application*` looking at the files in the current directory. If (as is normally the case) it finds nothing, it returns the glob pattern unaltered (supposing `bash` with default behavior here --- `zsh` will error out).
2. `apt-get` will remove the packages whose name **contains a string** that satisfies the regular expression `application*`, that is, `applicatio` followed by an arbitrary number of `n`: `applicatio`, `application`, `applicationn`, `libapplicatio`, etc.
3. To see how this can be dangerous, try (without root for double safety) `apt-get -s remove "wine*"` (`-s` will simulate the thing instead of doing it) --- it will say is going to remove all packages that has "win" in their name and the dependant, almost the entire system...

Probably, the command that was meant is really

```
 sudo apt-get remove "^application.*"
```

(note the quotes and the dot) which will remove all packages whose name starts with `application`.

These commands,

```
sudo updatedb                  # <-- updates the locate database (index). harmless
sudo locate application        # <-- locates the file 'application'. harmless
sudo rm -rf (file/folder name) # <-- removes files/dirs recursively. dangerous.
```

are completely outside the scope of the package management. Do not remove files belonging to packages without using the package manager! It will get confused and is the *wrong* way to do things.

If you don't know to which package a file belongs, try this:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

Comment: The --purge option is also handy when trying to fully remove any remaining dependencies including their config files: `apt-get-autoremove --purge`

It's also important to note that configuration files in your home directory are unaffected by the --purge option. These you will have to remove manually.

Comment: There was an error here: apt-get accepts RE, not globs; so apt-get remove pack* will remove all packages that starts with pac followed by zero or more k... which is normally unexpected. I edited the anser. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Comment: I think this answer is no longer accurate. Either `apt remove -s texlive*` or its `apt-get` counterpart return lines such as `Note, selecting 'texlive-font-utils' for glob 'texlive*'` (implying that they do indeed accept globs), followed by the usual `Package 'texlive-common' is not installed, so not removed`, and finally `Remv` lines, such as `Remv texlive-font-utils [2015.20160320-1] [...]`.

Comment: @JonathanY. You would also select not-installed packages. Anyway, could you please ask a NEW question and elaborate a bit more in detail what your situation is in the question. I would be happy to look at it :)

Comment: I'm not asking a new question. I'm pointing at a possible change since this answer was made that makes some of the details incorrect. To wit, it would seem that `apt-get remove packa*` does indeed take the glob `packa*` instead of looking at it as regex: it matches `package` but not `pack`.

Comment: @JonathanY. Ah, well, someone else added that section of the answer. See r7 in https://askubuntu.com/posts/187891/revisions. If you notice a globbing behaviour, you may be seeing the behaviour as explained in the [apt-get manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) (see "If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one ...")

Comment: I see. Well, I was commenting on the answer as it currently is. Anyway, that `man` page indeed says that an asterisk will cause the expression to be evaluated as regex, but that doesn't explain the behavior I'm seeing. E.g., `meld*` only matches package `meld`, but `meldt*` also matches `python-meld3` and `python3-meld3`. It's as if `apt-get` first tries to interpret the glob, and only if it fails tries to evaluate it as regex. **Edit**: now we *are* in the 'ask-new-question' realm. I'll do that.

Comment: ```apt-get remove``` lists orphaned dependencies and recommends ```apt autoremove``` to remove them.

Comment: Does it get any better with Ubuntu? `sudo apt-get remove --purge cheese`: `sudo: apt-get remove: command not found`

Answer (score 154):

For Ubuntu 12.04 and maybe higher, the correct method is:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename
```

As detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151943/20362).

Do not use `packagename*` as that can delete unintended packages and cause more problems than it solves.  Or if you must, at least run it with a `-s`, `--simulate`, `--dry-run` flag first to see exactly what it will do without doing it.

Comment: this is the correct answer, short and concise :

Answer (score 33):

You can use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove packagename
```

It will purge required packages along with dependencies that are installed with those packages. The `--auto-remove` option (being an alias of `autoremove`) works similar to `sudo apt-get autoremove`. By using this command we can run a single command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove packagename
```

Instead of:

```
sudo apt-get purge packagename
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Though you're correct, but one can also use `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename`. Same 1 command here

Comment: Can the complete command also be written as `apt-get autoremove --purge` instead of `apt-get purge --auto-remove` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can safely use `sudo apt-get remove --purge application` or `sudo apt-get remove applications` 99% of the time. When you use the `purge` flag, it simply removes all config files too. Which may or may not be what you want, depending on if you want to reinstall said application. The `application*` will match all applications that start with `application`, which are usually plugins, additional features, etc of the main application you are removing. i.e.

```
sudo apt-get remove gedit*
```

would remove `gedit`, `gedit-plugins` and `gedit-common`. Typically it is not necessary to do this, because most plugins/associated programs are dependent on the main application, and will automatically be removed (or marked for removal) when you uninstall the main application.

Your last command is just to remove leftovers from applications that are known to have messy uninstallers, and it is just removing any remnants of the application.

Answer (score 5):

I found this command in internet.

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends application
```

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Reinstalling_packages_to_fix_problems.

Answer (score 5):

I got some error messages removing a package, the only way I found that worked was this:

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/package.* /tmp/
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package
```

I found that although using only

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package
```

does not remove the package it shows me the correct path to the file to move with:

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/package.* /tmp/
```

Substitute package with your application name. Use sudo in Ubuntu, become root in Debian.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to clarify one thing that seems to be a source of confusion on here.
The `dpkg` utility does not know about or track packages dependencies in relation to one another, which was a big reason that `apt` was developed I believe. You can read about it in section 8.6 on this page [The Debian GNU/Linux FAQ - The Debian package management tools](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html)

- With apt: If I wanted to purge package A, and it has a dependency
  called package B, and package B had no other dependent packages, then
  package A and B will be purged. If package B DID have other dependent
  packages, then only package A will be purged.
- With dpkg: What dependency? You just told me to purge the damn
  package so that's what I did! Poor planning on your part does not
  constitute an emergency on my part.

With that said, here are two one-liners which can be used for each purge methods:

```
dpkg --list |grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --dry-run --purge

apt-get autoremove -y; apt-get --dry-run purge -y $(dpkg --list |grep '^rc' |awk '{print $2}')
```

Remove the `--dry-run` to perform the actual purge operation instead of reporting what actions it would have taken.

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. I had an issue where apt purge and autoremove didn't remove a package dependancy because it was suggested by another installed package. I was super lit about this because all the top answers always suggest purging followed by autoremove is enough. It isn't always. Thank you my dude. You would probably get more upvotes if you explained the commands in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application you want to remove. Always be sure to check its dependencies before issuing the yes command. When you remove something by command line, it will sometimes show a handful of libraries that are no longer needed. These can be removed with apt-get autoremove.

Beware that by using commands such as sudo apt-get remove --purge applicationname may remove some dependencies that are needed by other applications and, as such, might break your system.

If you want to do it in the safer way, you can always remove it using just the software center or apt-get remove applicationname. If the dependencies aren't needed anymore, issue apt-get autoremove later.

Comment: I think the whole Debian package system was designed specifically to *not* remove a package if there are other packages dependent on it. You may be (helpfully) asked if you want to remove all the dependent packages too, and that is where you should actually *read* the list of package about to be removed, which is *I think* what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything regarding the package package name like data and configuration, but not the dependencies installed with it on installation use:

```
apt-get remove --purge packagename
```