# How do I remove Deluge?

Tags: deluge

I've been an Ubuntu user for a little while, and everything has been going great until I installed Deluge.  I'd noticed some strange behaviour, so I uninstalled it, trying a bunch of different terminal commands.  Now I can't choose a a different torrent client like Transmission because Deluge is the only program still on the list.  How can I completely rid myself of Deluge?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would list the commands you have tried.  `sudo apt-get purge deluge` comes to mind.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would tell us how exactly you have installed it: using the software center? Manually downloading something? Using a command in the terminal? Something else?

Comment: [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Answer (score 1):

Run this in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge deluge
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt autoremove deluge-web
```