# How to completely remove application

Tags: package-management, uninstall

If I remove any application with `sudo apt-get remove <applicationName>`, the application is removed and then I can remove the repository later on.

I have noticed that certain cached and config files remain in the system. Some take up a large amount of space, e.g. GOOGLE-CHROME. It is hard to find and delete the remaining manually, as I am often not certain whether to delete them or not.

Is there any way to delete an application including the config and cache files along with the application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `sudo apt-get purge <package-name>` will remove `<package-name>` and all of it's config file that are not located in "Home" (`~`).

You will have to remove `config` files in your home directory manually.  Since these files are hidden you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to view them in Nautilus.

A good reference to look at:  [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/q/187888/44179d)

Comment: Then how to delete the config files that remain in the home directory?

Comment: You have to manually remove `config` files stored in your home folder, this is status-by-design or in other words a feature.

Comment: how to know which folder to delete, i mean they seem to be all over the place like CACHE, CONFIG, etc etc. Wow my home directory is a mess.

Comment: Guess i have to study the hidden files more to know which one belongs to whom. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, they have confusing names :/  I'd first want to know if Chrome even adds `config` files to `Home` though, it might store them else ware.  A good way to find out is to reinstall Google Chrome and see if it has any of your settings, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to remove all configuration files and all after uninstalling your software then you can use `Ubuntu tweak`. It is a very useful tool to do lots of things in Ubuntu, especially cleaning all unnecessary things.

The software is not in the official repo. of Ubuntu, but you can install it very easily using ppa. To install the software use the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Hope this information will be helpful to you.

Comment: The Janitor in Ubuntu tweak just removes the packages that are downloaded earlier and old kernals and some thumbnails also. But doesnot do what i want to achieve here.

Comment: There is option under `Janitor>System>Package config` which remove all the package configuration if you run it after uninstalling any package.

Comment: not working because i noticed `audacious` package is not showing, whereas the `audacious` is taking space in config in my home directory(i uninstalled audacious without `autoremove`). But, i noticed, my previous installed xfce was showing which i deleted earlier and thanks for this info i was able to delete them(where autoremove failed). I didnot knew that it was there in the system. I think it cleans configs of system wide stuffs or something like that. Anyways that is not clear yet. Thanks again friend. +1 for that dude.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall using GUI

just open Ubuntu Software Center. 
Once you open it go to installed
find your software by searching in the top right corner
then click remove

It will uninstall everything

Comment: Are you sure?  I thought this was equivalent of  `sudo apt-get remove <applicationName>`

Comment: Yeah, the `Software Center` doesn't remove config files. Generally, this is good. You might try uninstalling then reinstalling a program to solve a glitch, and you might not want to lose your settings in the process.