# reinstall virtualbox on ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, package-management

My virtualbox used to work, but now it is for some reason completely [FUBAR](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fubar): every time I try to start a VM, it crashes my host Ubuntu 12.04.1 system, I can't even bring it to reboot with the [Magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). I would like to clean up the mess and reinstall a working virtualbox.

I thought this would do:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
# reboot
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

But I get the same effect: even when downloading a fresh iso of any kind and starting the VM, it crashes the computer and I need to do a hard reboot.

EDIT: as per commented, I installed version 4.2 using these instructions:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

Ran virtualbox, checked the version: `4.2.6 r82870`

It didn't crash, so problem solved.
(copy+paste to answer)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [the packages from virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)? It's offering packages with closed-source components, but it's a bit newer and might work better. (on that page scroll down to "Debian-based Linux distributions") And make sure you remove all regular Ubuntu-shipped virtualbox packages first. If that works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks, that solved the problem. If you copy paste from EDIT to the end as an answer, I'll click on 'accept answer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As reported from the comments installing the packages from [virtualbox.org](http://www.virtualbox.org/) solved the issue.*

1. Remove the currently installed packages from the Ubuntu repositories.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove virtualbox\*
   ```
2. Add a new file to the APT sources, e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` with just this one line where `precise` is for 12.04 in your case, but should be replaced with the version of Ubuntu it's installed on:

   ```
   deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
   ```
3. Add the repository key to your APT GPG keyring to trust it:

   ```
   wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Update the lists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install the branch version you like by the package name, at this moment (`virtualbox-4.2`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
   ```
6. Add yourself and other users on the system to the `vboxusers` system group, by doing e.g.:

   ```
   sudo adduser username vboxusers
   ```
7. Now log out and log back in (or reboot). Yes, this is ugly, but your current running session isn't aware of the additional group you belong to now.
8. **Optional:** install the closed-source extension pack from the [general download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for "Support for USB 2.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP and PXE boot for Intel cards.".

   - Download the `.vbox-extpack` file.
   - In Virtualbox main screen, hit menu *File* -> *Preferences* -> vertical tab *Extensions*
   - Add the package there.

Done!

---

The reason for why the Ubuntu ones weren't working and these packages are *could* be:

- It's the open source version packaged, opposed to closed-source components from Virtualbox directly.
- Ubuntu [ships](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/virtualbox) an older 4.1.12 version at the time of writing whereas 4.1.22 is already released in the 4.1.x branch.
- You may have installed the completely newer 4.2 version of Virtualbox this way, not available in Ubuntu.

Either way, it's a bug in the Ubuntu packages. You might want to locate this bug on the Ubuntu bug tracker and report yourself affected.

Comment: Thanks, I reported the bug to launchpad. There is at least 1 more user that stumbled upon this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1083520

Answer (score 3):

Although you have a working solution, I'd like to give you some recommendations:

First of all, take a snapshot of your VMs.

When it's done, you should have used:

```
apt-get purge
```

instead of:

```
apt-get remove
```

You should probably have some misconfiguration or wrong config parameter/s, and that will clean it.

After that, install Virtual Box as usual, and import your snapshot.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I didn't know about `apt-get purge`.

Comment: @213441265152351 You might be interested in [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/a/187891/88802) for a further read on this.