# How uninstall a program?

Tags: uninstall

1. How is a program uninstalled in Ubuntu?

   1. By internet search I know to go to System/Administrator/something. Where is this so-called *"system"* found?
   2. What is this *"system"*? System sounds important.
2. Is it possible to uninstall Ubuntu One and Ubuntu Music and have their icons removed from the Launcher?

Comment: It depends on how it was installed.  Update your question with the way the application was installed.

Comment: Once you uninstall a program, the icon in the launcher will be removed. But if you only want to remove the icon from the launcher, and not removing the program, right-click over the icon and you will see the option to remove it.

Comment: If you are comfortable with the command line, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Answer (score 2):

Most software can be uninstalled via the softwarecenter: just serch for `ubuntu one` select the program you want to uninstall and click `remove`.

For more control, but also more possibilities to damage or crash your system you can install `synaptic package manager`.

Answer (score 2):

Through [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)

[image]

You can just click remove to uninstall it.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've found manuals relevant for old versions of Ubuntu which had [System menu on top panel](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=ubuntu%2010.10%20system%20administration%20menu&oq=ubuntu%2010.10%20system%20administration%20menu). It contained «Synaptic Package Manager» which is a great tool for installing and managing software. Currently, Ubuntu provides «Software Center» instead, but you still can use it to install Synaptic and then use Synaptic to install anything else.

I suppose, Ubuntu One can be removed (it is `ubuntuone-client` package in Synaptic), but be careful not to remove something important together with it. Synaptic always shows a warning when removing a package requires removing other packages, read it carefully in order to make sure that there is nothing important there. If there is, it's better not to remove Ubuntu One.

> What is this "system"? System sounds important.

In Linux, most software is installed not only for current user but system-wide, so installing, removing and updating software requires administration privileges (also known as `root` privileges). That's why package management is considered a «system» operation and usually placed into «System» menu.

Anyway, if you just want to remove an icon from Unity left panel, right-click on it and remove. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using unity, if so [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5cI3a62uG8) might help, or [this tutorial](http://captainjamie.byethost12.com/installing_software/). Also, just search the dash for Ubuntu one and Ubuntu music to open them without the launcher, [like this](http://captainjamie.byethost12.com/unity/#programs) tutorial says, under finding programs.