# How do I completely uninstall and old version of Redis?

Tags: uninstall

I'm trying to upgrade to redis version 2.6.13 and I want to remove all old versions on my ubuntu 12.04 system.

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: I followed the redis quickstart
http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Comment: Okay, so just to be clear, you installed from upstream source (using `make`)? Then it's hard to provide support here. Next time, make sure you install **packages** - those are easy to uninstall, upgrade, list, etc.

Comment: @gertvdijk, this is correct but not possible in some situations. i.e. when the package in the repo is too old or not given and in this case the quickstart guide suggest to compile the program manualy.

Comment: Sorry I was misinformed by my friend that installed it.
He did a "sudo apt-get install redis-server"

Comment: @Ryan In that case: [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/q/187888/88802)

Answer (score 1):

There is a make-command but no make-install-command. Because of this, I think it is enough to delete just the main-folder (where you executed the make-command) and every file you copied to any location on your filesystem according to the guide.

Comment: Good point. It's installed by hand - by copying files. So undoing that (`rm`) should be sufficient indeed.