# Force apt-get to ask all install questions again?

Tags: apt, configuration

While installing `jackd` using apt-get, I gave the wrong answer to some questions. How do I force apt-get to ask me the question again? I'd really rather do this through the package manager than making the changes manually.

I tried to purge it and install it again. I have also tried `dpkg-reconfigure jackd`.

Comment: apt asks a question when its about to install more than you asked. in other words the dependencies of that app you asked to install. so the 1st time it installed them. when you purged the app, dependencies were left there untouched. you can use synaptic to find all useless dependencies that currently are useless or use dpkg to sort packages per date and find them manually and unistall them, or just forget about them. to get a question again now to install that specific app do what they suggest on their answers below

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that `dpkg-reconfigure` *is* the solution, but sometimes the package to which the question belongs is not named the same as the package you installed - either because it was a meta-package, or because the question belonged to one of the dependent packages.

In that case, it can be helpful to look at the debconf database to see if there is a likely candidate, using `debconf-show` e.g.

```
$ sudo debconf-show --listowners | grep jack
jackd2
```

and it turns out that

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure jackd2
```

does indeed prompt the question that you are looking for.

Comment: This does not help for packages which are installed into the wrong places, when `dpkg-reconfigure` leaves unwanted (and possibly dangerous) debris behind.  Example: `gitloite3`

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of the reader in case you stumble over a similar thing, this here helps to solve following problem(s):

- After a package is installed you see, that many things are at the wrong place.
- `dpkg-reconfigure package` does not help either, as this might leave unwanted (or even dangerous) debris behind (for example, when switching to username `git` for package `gitolite3` it  does not clean up the default `gitolite3` user - as it cannot know if this user was used in the meanwhile).
- After uninstalling the package, Debian still "magically" remembers the last values entered at the next install.
- You can see some package configuration values on `dpkg-reconfigure`, which are not asked on `apt-get install`
- You hate Curses-GUIs or love plain text consoles

## Have `apt` ask for every possible configuration value

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt-get install PACKAGE`

However, this might not ask for everything if there are already cached answers.  These are kept in something called `debconf`.  The file where it is kept is called `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat`.

To see all this information, run following command, perhaps before you try to install `PACKAGE`:

```
debconf-show PACKAGE
```

See below on some ways to get rid of unwanted entries (there are zillion of more ways, of course).

> Warning:
>
> Never ever edit `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` on your own.  Look at it, but do not alter it with an editor.  It's a picky file.  Spaces, TABs, etc., do not touch these, keep them as-is.  Some editors try to do clever things with spaces in text files.  They will destroy `config.dat`.  And most time you cannot even see it.
>
> Instead use the proper tools (some are in `debconf-utils`):
>
> - `debconf-get-selections` to dump everything
> - `debconf-set-selections` to set things
> - `debconf-show PACKAGE` to see all debconf parameters of `PACKAGE` (this is everything `dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGE` would ask)
> - `echo PURGE | debconf-communicate PACKAGE` to [delete all debconf information of a PACKAGE](https://serverfault.com/a/332490)
>
> But beware, these are not designed for normal people.

## How to get rid of everything of a package

> Warning!  `apt-get purge` (aka. `apt-get remove --purge`) might destroy valuable user data.  Be sure you kept a backup, just in chance.  You have been warned.

The opposite of `apt-get install PACKAGE` is `apt-get remove --purge PACKAGE`.  Nowadays we can write `apt-get purge PACKAGE` for this, too.  Without purging, some things are left behind, such that you can quickly install the PACKAGE again with all the previous settings and data intact.  This includes all the questions asked when the PACKAGE was installed the first time.

However `apt-get purge PACKAGE` removes all traces of the PACKAGE, including it's configuration and quite often even valuable user data which was stored by or for the PACKAGE will be removed entirely as well!

So if you see, that something went wrong when installing a PACKAGE, you can use `apt-get purge PACKAGE` to get rid of it, such that you can try again to install it correctly.  Later, after you have used PACKAGE a while, `apt-get purge PACKAGE` probably comes out very evil.

Note that `apt-get purge PACKAGE` sometimes leaves debris behind when a package was reconfigured with `dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGE`, because `purge` operates on what is known at "purge-time", and not what was before that, because there is little to no history about what was before the last `dpkg-reconfigure`.

But if you are sure there is no valuable data left which is not backed up and you want to start from fresh with some package, do an `apt-get purge PACKAGE`.  Note that you can do this even after a package was removed with `apt-get remove PACKAGE`.

## How to find the package

You have know a file, but do not know which package it belongs to, this finds it:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

If this does not output anything, it does not belong to a PACKAGE.  So perhaps it is user data or debris.  You decide.

For a COMMAND you can type (note that the quotes are important) to find it's PACKAGE:

```
dpkg -S "`which COMMAND`"
```

It you found the package, you can get a list of all files in a package:

```
dpkg -L PACKAGE
```

(Note that this does not include some files, which are generated by the install scripts.)

However finding a package only works for installed packages.  If you need the same info for not yet installed packages, try the tool `apt-file search filename` (you need to run `apt-file update` first to initialize it's database).

## To sum it up

- You have a PACKAGE already installed and want to reconfigure it

  ```
  dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGE
  ```
- You want to re-install a PACKAGE with the current settings
      apt-get install --reinstall PACKAGE
- You want to re-install a PACKAGE from scratch, with deletion of all previous (possible precious) data, and have all possible questions asked again:

  ```
  apt-get purge PACKAGE
  DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt-get install PACKAGE
  ```
- If you dislike Curses interface and want a line-driven interface

  add `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline` in front of `apt-get`
- If you even dislike the readline interface and want dead simple line editing as well

  add `TERM=dumb` in front of `apt-get` (note that this is nothing special from `debconf`, this works since Unix was born).

(Note that you can set this in the Environment as well like `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline`, of course.)

## FYI

The best source known to me, where debconf is explained, such that you can really understand it, and where I took most of the details for this here, is following link, but the page is in German language:

http://debiananwenderhandbuch.de/debconf.html

BTW:

- I write this as a reference to myself, too, because I cannot remember all the details.  It's all just too exotic and mostly absent from the man pages.
- This answer is too long.  Which probably means, `apt` and `debconf` are still too confusing.

Comment: to know which package belongs where is hard... you must have the memory of an elephant haha ! but using dpkg to sort by date is something its easier to remember , find and uninstall. for example i can remember i installed those apps on friday, but i can't remember 20+ packages names !

Comment: The post is so long because it includes the answers to two separate, but related questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file and http://askubuntu.com/q/187888/158442

Comment: Thanks for noting, but an answer is no answer when it raises more questions than it solves.  The information "how to have `apt` ask everything" is so well hidden in the docs, that most will be at a point, where it is too late when they notice.  Perhaps packages were installed as recommends.  So you need a) a way to locate the package and b) clean it up, such that you can apply the answer.  Also cleanups need to be done properly, which is a problem by itself.  Hence I must give the right pointers.  Thanks for adding the links to them!  That is very welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

I too just ran into this same issue (*on Ubuntu Server 18.04*) where I had installed jackd and wanted to reconfigure it to enable the realtime priorities, which I had selected **No** to on the initial installation.

I still had the installation text displayed on my screen when I scrolled back. (*via Shift-PageUp*) and when I saw these two lines:

```
Setting up jackd1 (1:0.125.0-3) ...
Setting up jackd (5) ...
```

I figured I could try reconfiguring **jackd1** instead of **jackd**.

Sure enough, I did a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure jackd1` and I was prompted for the realtime question again.

When I answered yes this time, it changed the 
**/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf.disabled** file into **/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf** which is what I sort of expected.

Out of curiosity, I issued the command that @steeldriver did, and my system did show **jackd1** instead of **jackd2**, so that all makes sense.

```
sudo debconf-show --listowners | grep jack
jackd1
```