# Cannot remove NGINX

Tags: apt, 14.04, uninstall, nginx

I have been experimenting with nginx as a webserver for php files. I come from an Apache background but I wanted to try it. I recently had an issue with it and needed to switch back to Apache. I removed it using `apt-get remove nginx`.

This worked fine and I installed Apache and life was good. I restarted my computer and somehow nginx started up. I didn't understand. I tried to remove it again and I got the [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNLBX.png):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

If I look for the program ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iIP6.png)):

```
$ which nginx
/usr/sbin/nginx
```

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong or what the next step to removing it would be?

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get purge nginx`? You can try reinstalling it, then purging it.

Comment: I tried reinstalling and purging. Its still there :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`nginx` is a metapackage, so you need to remove whatever was installed by this package. If doing `sudo apt-get autoremove` doesn't do the trick, you can run `sudo apt-get remove nginx-core nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras nginx-naxsi nginx-common` (you probably have only one of these packages installed, but the command shouldn't fail).

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how I can determine which packages are meta packages?

Comment: I typically go by the size of the package. If the Installed-Size of the package (`apt-cache show nginx`, or `apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop`) is less than 100, then there's a good chance that it's just a metapackage, and to look at the dependencies (which may point to a specific version or variant of the software). Also, packages that are in the `metapackages` section are certain to be metapackages; however, not all metapackages are in the `metapackages` section.

Comment: The most possible ones would be nginx-core & nginx-common. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*` will remove whatever is installed and is related to nginx, including configuration files. It will also list packages available in repositories which match the regex `nginx*` and are not installed.

There is a [difference between `apt-get remove` and `apt-get purge`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application). The `--purge` option removes also the configuration files. It is useful for a clean reinstall.

Typing the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*
```

will result in:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
nginx-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 55416 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nginx-common ...
Purging configuration files for nginx-common ...
```