# How to totally remove the nginx from ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, nginx

I have un-install all the nginx related packages.(like this answer said https://askubuntu.com/a/457412/383308), after that I run the command below command gives nothing.

```
sudo find / -name 'nginx'
```

When I run such command, I have one result:

```
zyh@zyh-desktop:~$ ps -ef | grep nginx
zyh       2666  2442  0 11:12 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

But when I open the browser, and enter 127.0.0.1, I still see a welcome page of the nginx. See below:
[image: nginx web service is still alive]

I think my problem is quite similar to this one [[SOLVED] nginx running, but ... not installed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2202323), but after run the command

```
sudo update-rc.d -f nginx remove
sudo rm /etc/init.d/nginx
```

And after the reboot, I can still see the nginx page from 127.0.0.1. Any ideas how to totally remove nginx. Thanks.

PS: I have used the `auto-remove` option to uninstall all the `nginx*` packages, and I see that my desktop is removed, and I later install a new ubuntu desktop.

**EDIT**
It looks like I can open a python http server on the 80 port, such as below

```
zyh@zyh-desktop:~/Downloads/code/share-file$ sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServerWithUpload 80
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80 ...
```

While when I open the Firefox browser, and type 127.0.0.1, I still see the nginx welcome page.

Answer (score 10):

Please stop *nginx* first then try it to remove:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx-core nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras nginx-naxsi nginx-common
```

Comment: Hi, Ramesh, thanks for the answer. I found I have made a big mistake, because when I see from the Firefox is looks like the cached page of 127.0.0.1. I have take a lot of time to try to remove or clean up the nginx process or services from my Ubuntu. But now, I see that after clear the cache of Firefox, I can't see the welcome page from Firefox, sorry.

Comment: My problem was not Firefox cache -- I could still issue status/start/stop commands to nginx and it was very annoying because I wanted apache2 to be the default web server. To resolve my issue, I ran: `sudo service nginx stop` then your `sudo apt purge nginx nginx-common` then `sudo reboot`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the web page in my question(see the screen shot above) is a cached page, and follow the methods mentioned in this post:[How can I clear a single site from the cache in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox), I just clear the cache, and now, I see Firefox can't connect to 127.0.0.1 now. Sorry about the noise.

Which means the nginx is already un-installed from my Ubuntu.