# apt-get remove says nginx not installed, but it is still running

Tags: apt, nginx

I `sudo apt-get install nginx` by mistake on a server already running Apache.

I then `sudo apt-get remove nginx` and rebooted. I lost the output of that and can't remember if it was installed successfully. If I tried that again, it says "Package 'nginx' is not installed so not removed."

However, if I now run `sudo nginx -t` it says "test is successful". And `which nginx` shows `/usr/sbin/nginx`.

What is the real status? How do I properly uninstall nginx?

Comment: You might also want to read [Unable to uninstall package with error "Unable to locate package"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078550/212930)

Comment: Also, [Cannot remove NGINX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457040/cannot-remove-nginx) seems applicable here.

Comment: To uninstall any app you use the revers command used to install it. Apt get install is apt get remove, snap install is snap remove for example.

Comment: The referenced link: `apt-get remove --purge nginx*` did the trick.