# Complete removal of all bluetooth related packages

Tags: uninstall, bluetooth

I have a poorly powered netbook and I would like to safely "trim the fat" from my 14.04 install.

What I'm looking to do is remove all traces of bluetoothd (a service that does not seem to want to take "no" for an answer when it comes to loading at boot time), and all other bluetooth related software.

My netbook doesn't support BT, and  I have no desire to ever use it in the future.

I have had little luck finding out if anyone has tried this before, and I would like to be able to have some idea if it is safe to completely purge.

Your help finding the correct information is appreciated.  Ask questions if you need to, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

see [for reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/479118)

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This works best for me.