# Complete Deletion/Reinstallation of Downloaded Package

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, debian, aptitude

I want to know how to delete every file installed by a package using either aptitude or apt-get and then re-download and re-install that package completely again.

I've tried doing aptitude reinstall apache2 apache2-doc after running aptitude purge apache2 apache2-doc but that doesnt work.

What I did was I deleted my /etc/apache2 directory thinking I could just reinstall it (I was having PHP integration issues) but now whenever I try to install it I get the error "invoke-rc.d initscript apache, action "reload" failed."

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Everything is explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application).