# Xubuntu to Lubuntu

Tags: apt, xubuntu, lubuntu

I am using Xubuntu and i want to change Lubuntu.I have copy the code from http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purelubuntu and run in terminal.

The output of `apt-get` is listed here:

```
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done   
Package 'gnome-games-data' is not installed, so not removed   
Package 'libsnmp15' is not installed, so not removed  
Package 'ttf-droid' is not installed, so not removed   
E: Unable to locate package firefox-gnome-support  
E: Unable to locate package ibus-pinyin-db-android  
E: Unable to locate package ibus-pinyin-db-open-phrase  
E: Unable to locate package libbrlapi0.5  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libbrlapi0.5'  
E: Unable to locate package libdotconf1.0  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libdotconf1.0'  
E: Unable to locate package libical0  
E: Unable to locate package libotr2
```

**Can i remove these libraries from terminal?**

Comment: Which version of *Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The article you're using as a guide is very old - and was written for a version of Xubuntu from 3 years ago, which is no longer supported. Current versions of Xubuntu include a different suite of packages than that release did.

- When it says "Package 'foobar' is not installed, so not removed" - that means you never had that package in the first place, so don't worry about it.
- When it says "E: Unable to locate package foobar" or "E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'foobar'" - that probably means that exact package is not included in your version of Xubuntu. You could have a similar package with a different name, but you might not.

**What you don't see is all of the packages that are included in *your version* of Xubuntu that you want to uninstall, but the system is not uninstalling** because they are not included in that 3-year old list.

For those reasons, the simplest way to replace xubuntu with lubuntu would be to run these three commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

And then, after logging out and logging in using LXDE (the Lubuntu desktop):

```
sudo apt-get purge xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Some miscellaneous files or packages may still remain from your Xubuntu installation. If you would like to be as thorough as that guide was, I would recommend running:

```
apt-cache depends xubuntu-desktop > ~/xubuntu-desktop-depends.txt
apt-cache depends lubuntu-desktop > ~/lubuntu-desktop-depends.txt
```

and remove anything from the first list that does not appear on the second with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge package1 package2 ...
```

...etc, where each package to be removed is separated by one space.

using the "apt-get purge" command also removes configuration files, except those in your home directory. For more info on that, see here: [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Comment: Thanks for your Post.. I remove that packages from that code. works Fine

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.

In the Grub menu select the line which starts with ---- Advanced options.

Select the line ending with ---- (recovery mode) something like:

Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic (recovery mode)

Press Enter key and your machine will begin the boot process.

Your pc should display a menu with a number of options.

Select the line will be ---- Drop to root shell prompt, press enter with this option highlighted.

In the terminal run it:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(lubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(xubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(lubuntu-desktop))))'

apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your Post.. I remove that packages from that code. works Fine