# Completely Uninstall Spideroak

Tags: uninstall

I tried to remove Spideroak with autoremove command. But I still have the Spideroak Hive. Can somebody help me, how to remove Spideroak completely. Thanks

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Got the files from the  website, and then open and install it with Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package_name>`

Comment: Related- http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you could have done that with ...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge spideroak
```

But you need to delete that yourself since it is a user folder. From their site:

> **Deleting your SpiderOak Hive**
>
> When you uninstall SpiderOak, your SpiderOak Hive folder will remain.
>   However, the files in Hive will no longer be synced.
>
> To delete the SpiderOak Hive folder, you must delete the actual folder
>   itself. Deleting shortcuts to the folder will not remove the folder
>   and its data from your computer. Make sure you have removed any files
>   and folders you wish to save from your Hive before deleting the
>   folder.
>
> ```
> Linux users: the original folder can be found at /Users//SpiderOak Hive/"
> ```

So from command line

```
rm -rf ~/SpiderOak Hive/
```

- Tip: use "tab" to autocomplete it so the space is correctly shown ;)
- Warning: this WILL delete all your files inside the directory.

You can also delete it from Nautilus (go to Home and shift-delete the directory).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 (at least) the package is now called spideroakone.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge spideroakone`

Then delete (or rename if you might use it again later) the directory:

`/home/user/.config/SpiderOakONE/`

You might also be able to remove it in the Installed section of the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

First purge the package itself:

```
sudo apt-get purge spideroak
```

Then you should remove the directory created in your home named `SpiderOak Hive`