# After removing a package, more packages are removed

Tags: apt, package-management

After I type in my shell:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove openssl
```

I got more than just openssl packages removed, why?

Below is partial output:

```
(Reading database ... 400426 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nautilus-share (0.7.3-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing apturl (0.5.2ubuntu4) ...
Removing bluez-cups (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Removing google-chrome-stable (43.0.2357.124-1) ...
```

Comment: Look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application and read carefully `apt-get --help` and `man apt-get`

Comment: Why do you try to remove opened to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they depend on something you just said to remove - `openssl` is the dependency in question. None of those programs can run without it.

For example, when I install something, have a look at the output:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  chkrootkit john john-data procmail sendmail sendmail-base sendmail-bin
  sendmail-cf sensible-mda tripwire
```

That is because the package I want to install (`tiger`) needs these - they are dependencies.

Well the same has happened here. `nautilus-share`, `apturl`, `bluez-cups` and `google-chrome-stable` all need `openssl` to run - so they are uninstalled at the same time.

Next time you remove something, you will may see something like this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  akregator amarok amarok-utils anoise anoise-media apport-kde
  apt-xapian-index apturl-kde ark audiocd-kio bluedevil blueproximity
```

If you see something you want, don't remove the main package. In the case above, I was going to remove `python` - but that would remove a lot (231) of things.

Comment: But should not apt-get remove --purge packagename, leave those dependencies? Guess I should read man pages more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear. The dependency is *what you are removing*.

Comment: Timmy, thats a really good explanation.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the dependencies with `aptitude why`:

```
$ aptitude why openssl
i   ca-certificates Depends openssl (>= 1.0.0)
$ aptitude why ca-certificates
i   software-properties-common Depends ca-certificates
$ aptitude why software-properties-common 
i   software-properties-gtk Depends software-properties-common
$ aptitude why software-properties-gtk 
i   ubuntu-desktop Depends software-properties-gtk

$ aptitude why apturl
i   nautilus-share Depends apturl
$ aptitude why nautilus-share
i   ubuntu-desktop Recommends nautilus-share
```

So, this shows that `openssl` is installed because it is a dependency of `ca-certificates`.
`ca-certificates` is a dependency of `software-properties-common` which again is a dependency of `software-properties-gtk`.
`software-properties-gtk` finally is a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop`. So all of these will be removed if you remove `openssl`. They recursive depend on `openssl`.

Because of `ubuntu-desktop` gets removed and `nautilus-share` is recommended by `ubuntu-desktop` (and most likely has no other reason for being installed) it will be removed, too. same goes with `apturl`