# I do not have Squid installed on my Ubuntu system but receive squid error?

Tags: squid

When I type sudo curl ifconfig.me it returns my ip, but when I type the same without sudo I get a squid Access Denied error?

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Have you *ever* had squid installed on your computer???

Comment: I have, and I have tried to open the conf file just in case it was still there, but cant find it, if it is.  curl ifconfig.me was working fine this morning and now I get this error. I must have the file somewhere.  How could I find it?

Comment: install squid again and then [remove it completely](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application) and report back.

Comment: @Fabby, it just started working again, strangest thing. But done what you advised. All seems to be fine now, thank you very much for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: Don't go away yet!  Answer coming up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like last time you tried to uninstall squid, it wasn't removed completely, therefore *first install squid again*:

```
apt install squid
```

and *then* remove *and purge it completely*:

```
apt purge squid
```

Now squid *and all of its dependencies are fully removed* and the problem will have gone away.