# Removing games from Dash

Tags: uninstall

I would like to permanatly remove AisleRiot Solitare and all of the games from dash, so I am not tempted to play them.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you uninstall them then, instead of just removing them from Dash?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal and use:

```
sudo apt purge aisleriot gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku  && sudo apt autoremove
```