# Uninstalling Node and NPM

Tags: software-uninstall

I'm trying to [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/738579) nodejs and npm, but although I can see current version, I can't uninstall it.

[This is what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCz1i.png)

**output locate -w npm:**

```
home/juliana/snap/notepad3/common/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/gecko/plugin/npmshtml.dll
/home/juliana/snap/notepad3/common/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64/gecko/plugin/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-devel/lib/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-devel/lib/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-devel/lib64/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-devel/lib64/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-stable/lib/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-stable/lib/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-stable/lib64/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-stable/lib64/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-staging/lib64/wine/npmshtml.dll.so
/snap/wine-platform/128/opt/wine-staging/lib64/wine/fakedlls/npmshtml.dll
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/README.md
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/dist
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/images
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/package.json
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/package.nls.json
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/dist/main.js
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/dist/nls.metadata.header.json
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/dist/nls.metadata.json
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/images/npm_icon.png
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark/continue.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark/debug.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark/prepostscript.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark/refresh.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/dark/script.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light/continue.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light/debug.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light/prepostscript.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light/refresh.svg
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/resources/light/script.svg
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-13/include/xen/interface/xenpmu.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-15/include/xen/interface/xenpmu.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly did you install nodejs? Did you use apt or something like the snap store (since I can see you have a few other snap packages installed).

A better command to run is `which`, which will return the the path of the executable being called, so something like `which node` or `which npm` would be more useful. Also, since I'm assuming you actually used a snap package, `sudo snap list` would be helpful.

If you are indeed using the snap package, you probably want `sudo snap remove node`.

As a side note, avoid logging in as root and using it. You have sudo for administrative tasks, so take advantage of it and get used to better and safer practices.

Also, if you are looking to remove it so you can update to a newer version, take a look at this github page with the generally recommend ways of installing node.

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall

Comment: thanks, i think i solved my problem already, but it's a great answer