# Uninstalling node and npm and then again reinstalling

Tags: 20.04, nodejs, npm

I have run into an [issue] and looking to remove nodejs and npm completely and then install again. I have installed node from the terminal. What's the best way to do it? My system is Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Current version:

```js
node -v
v12.16.3

npm -v
6.14.4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstalling Node and NPM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145725/uninstalling-node-and-npm)

Comment: It does not tell how to uninstall node and npm. I have installed node from the repository. The answer was just talking about the snap uninstall.

Answer (score 5):

If you used `apt install nodejs` and `apt install npm`, you can remove it with `apt purge nodejs` and `apt purge npm`.

But if you used snap, then you can run the following command: `snap remove node`.

Comment: That worked like a charm.