# How to purge an application via Ubuntu-Software-Center with all its dependencies?

Tags: software-center, purge

As far as I now, if you install an app with `sudo apt install app` you can then remove it via `sudo apt remove app` or `sudo apt purge app`. I think the difference is that the second method will also remove all application dependencies, like application settings. If I install an application, let's say visual studio code via Ubuntu-Software-Center, save some settings within vscode and then uninstall it via Ubuntu-Software, the settings are stored. I can see that when I reinstall it via Ubuntu-Software-Center, but I definitely don't want that! If I remove an application it shall be gone and free all the memory that it took. I don't see an option to really purge installed applications - How can I remove applications that I installed via Ubuntu-Software-Center, including all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Software Center does not currently have functionality equivalent to `apt purge <package name>`. To completely remove the application and configuration files from your computer you will need to use the command line and complete some manual cleanup.

From the man pages for apt `man apt`:

> Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small (modified)user configuration files behind, in case the remove was an accident.
>   Just issuing an installation request for the accidentally removed package will restore its function as before in that case. 
>   On the other hand you can get rid of these leftovers by calling purge even on already removed packages. 
>   Note that this does not affect any data or configuration stored in your home directory.

This indicates running `apt purge <package name>`twice may be necessary as well as manually deleting files left behind in the user's home directory `~` and (likely) `~./.config`.

Though posted a while back, you may find this reference useful ([What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application))