# How do I remove chromium browser completely from 20.04

Tags: 20.04, chromium

I have installed chromium from ubuntu software
I first tried to install it first using sudo apt-get install chromium-browser but the process stuck there and I saw lot of comments on it. So I killed that process and used ubuntu software to install it. And later I used the ubuntu software to remove it and restarted.

I also used the commands

> rm -rf ~/.config/chromium

> rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium

> sudo rm -rf /etc/chromium

But I still see some files in the root folder

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Help he completely remove the files. I don't know which is which.

Comment: You're finding files unrelated to chromium. Spotify for example uses chromium embedded framework.

Comment: @Nmath I used sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser and later used the rm commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Comment: @Nmath Thank you. This cleared my doubt.

Comment: @Nmath unrelated but if you could help me with this it would be great. When I am trying to share my screen on google meet (from firefox) and teams application, I am able to share mic audio but my screen audio i.e., say a youtube video , is not sharing. Is it a problem with firefox or the teams application ? That is the whole reason I installed chromium. And I found that audio was getting shared in chromium through google meet.

Comment: Chromium browser can only now be installed on 20.04 by Snap. It cannot be installed from a deb package now. So using apt-get install/remove is useless. If you upgraded from an earlier version of Ubuntu where it was installed by a deb package there will only be fragments of old Chromium files left. To get rid of them run `sudo find / -iname *chromium* -delete`. If you want to do a dry run first, omit the *-delete* bit.

Comment: I don't know enough about google meet to give any assistance on it, but you can definitely provide the details about that problem by asking another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't worry too much about "complete removal". Your system will not loose performance in any way. At worst, some disk space will still be occupied.

Chromium is installed as a Snap. When removing, the program files are automatically erased from your disk. Your user configuration for chromium is automatically backed up in a system folder and purged automatically after 30 days.

What will remain, is a "chromium" folder in your "snap" folder right in your home folder, containing very few items. Feel free to remove that. Leave the rest to the automated framework for installing and removal of software, with which you interacted through Ubuntu Software.